# Kentor.AuthServices configuring thumbprint validation

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, wif, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

How do I configure [Kentor.AuthServices](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) to use the issuer registry from WIF? Specifically, to check based on thumbprint like in the example below:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
          <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089">
            <trustedIssuers>
              <add thumbprint="1111111111111" name="http://some.domain/adfs/services/trust" />
            </trustedIssuers>
          </issuerNameRegistry>
          <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None"/>
        </securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
```

I tried this (stripped out everything but the `<identityProviders>` element before posting):

```
  <kentor.authServices>
    <identityProviders>
      <add entityId="http://some.domain/adfs/services/trust" destinationUrl="https://some.domain/adfs/ls" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpPost">
        <signingCertificate findValue="1111111111111" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
      </add>
    </identityProviders>
  </kentor.authServices>
```

But this gives me "Missing signing certificate configuration on Idp http://some.domain/adfs/services/trust"

Is there a way to do the equivalent in Kentor, or (better yet) is there a way to feed this existing WIF config into Kentor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently (version 0.12.0), there is no way to set an own `IssuerNameRegistry`. This is however something that I'm looking into, as part of [#145](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/145).

The change is however non-trivial, as it's not just to feed a configured `IssuerNameRegistry` to WIF because that only covers the case where the assertion itself is signed. If the signature is on the message level, the validation is done by AuthServices itself, so that code also has to be changed to use the `IssuerNameRegistry`.